# jQuery Get Image Errors after Ajax f.e

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, image

This works fine, when the page is loading, but when I load other pictures with AJAX, this wouldn`t work. Any Ideas?

```
var error_img_list = "";    
    $('img').error(function(){
            if(error_img_list.indexOf($(this).attr("src")) < 1){
            $.post("includes/error_pic.php",
                                    {
                                        mode: "missing_pic",
                                        src: $(this).attr("src"),
                                        url: window.location.href ,
                                        html: $(this).parent().html()

                                    },
                                    function(data, status){
                                        if(status == "success"){
                                            //...
                                        }
            });

            error_img_list = error_img_list+","+$(this).attr("src");
            }
            $(this).attr('src', '/img/missing.png');            
    });
```

Comment: Did you check the console? Is there a specific error you are getting?

Comment: only the "404 image no found" error from the image itselfs @Kmeixner